# How to detect whether user selected entire document or not in HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

I'm developing a off-line web-page for iPhone Safari.

For highlighting the user's selection in web-page. I've implemented following code.

```
function highlight() {

    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
        document.designMode = "on";
        if (range) {
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }        
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");       
        document.designMode = "off";
    }
}
```

That's working perfectly for normal selection.

**Edit :**

How to detect has user selected entire document or not?

What to do?

Comment: You have do declare the variables that you use inside the function. Otherwise they become implied globals (which is something that you certainly don't want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a function that will return a Boolean indicating whether all of the contents of the specified element are selected and works in all major browsers, including IE. You can use this with `document.body` to test whether the whole page is selected.

```
function areElementContentsSelected(el) {
    var range, elRange;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            elRange = document.createRange();
            elRange.selectNodeContents(el);
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(i);
                if (range.compareBoundaryPoints(range.START_TO_START, elRange) <= 0 && range.compareBoundaryPoints(range.END_TO_END, elRange) >= 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        elRange = range.duplicate();
        elRange.moveToElementText(el);
        return range.compareEndPoints("StartToStart", elRange) <= 0 && range.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", elRange) >= 0;
    }
    return false;
}

alert( areElementContentsSelected(document.body) );
```

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't want to allow user to select entire document & highlight it.

Why not?

Interfering with users' typically-expected-browsing-experience is never a good thing and usually leads to frustrated users simply disabling JS or choosing to abandon your site altogether.

Please reconsider.

Comment: Ok ! allow - but how to detect it ?

Comment: Consider not using the word "never". There are always exceptions. The phrase "generally not" would be a far better choice here. Also, I would guess that around 95% of the web-users don't know how to turn JavaScript off.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [`selectNodeContents(document body)`](http://javascript.gakaa.com/range-selectnode-4-0-5-2-0-selectnodecontents-4-0-5-.aspx) (pseudocode) to create a range representing the whole page, and then compare that to the range that the user selected?